# Help center link in off-topic close reason here should point to "What's Meta"

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, meta

The general off-topic close reason on this meta links to the main Stack Overflow help center:

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

It think it would be better to point at the [What's Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page, especially since the "What's on topic" page in the main help center doesn't talk about Meta at all.

(I checked on the Unix & Linux and DBA metas, that's what happens there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was changed at some point to link to Stack Overflow's [What's meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page. That's pretty good too.